# rails 4 double has_many includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have difficulties with double has_many & includes

There is a twitter-style app (with Users, Tweets, and Likes)

```
class User
  has_many :tweets # direct tweets
  has_many :likes # liked tweets
end

class Tweet
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :likes

class Like
  belongs_to :like
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is spreads query:

```
@tweets = Tweet.first(20).includes(:likes) # I need to do includes or joins et.c.
```

I have a partial which rendering one tweet and saying to current_user about his like status to particular tweet (something like that):

```
(tweet.likes & current_user.likes).any? # I can't do efficient query here
```

And I get classic n+1 query. What should I do to prevent it?

Comment: How does `current_user.likes` know what tweet it's referring to? If you're looping over `current_user.likes`, Rails will cache it. But if you're looping over `current_user.likes.where(tweet_id: tweet.id)`, then you'll get an extra db call every iteration.

Comment: @evanbikes what is solution? There are a lot of tweets

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class User
  has_many :tweets # direct tweets
  has_many :likes # liked tweets
end

class Tweet
  belongs_to :user 
  has_many :likes, through: :users

class Like
  belongs_to :like
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your partial, I presume you want the current_user's likes for *that* tweet.

In that case, I would do this in the view:

```
current_user_likes_for_tweet = current_user.likes.select { |a| a.tweet_id == tweet.id }
(tweet.likes & current_user_likes_for_tweet).any?
```

This way, `current_user.likes` will be cached by Rails and you're just doing a filter on an array in memory.

You could *also* do this:

**Controller**

```
@current_user_likes = current_user.likes.group_by(&:tweet_id)
```

**View**

```
(tweet.likes & @current_user_likes[tweet.id].to_a).any? # to_a because it might be nil
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. It can be solved just by right include query.

Comment: Else one trouble is ability to write `@current_user_likes` in the many places in the controller

Comment: Also here instantiated a lot of AR objects, which are slow too